# Hibernate - How to read configuration from another web application project?

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I have a Java web application that uses Hibernate entities (with annotations) and also contains Hibernate's configuration (such as dialect and the list of mapped entities) in a beans.xml file.

I want to write a new simple Java application (not a web-app) that will use the same Hibernate entities and configuration, except for the connection properties (URL, user, password).

I need to somehow read the configuration from the web-app, and only change the connection properties on run-time (the app expects to get the connection properties as input).
I also want the app to connect to more than one DB simultaneously with that configuration.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be defining a DataSource in your context and letting Hibernate use it, instead of specifying the connection parameters directly to Hibernate. An example for Tomcat is available [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). The idea then is to have the persistence.xml consuming the data source from Tomcat.

I don't really know how it would behave with two different contexts with the same data source name, but if it doesn't work, you can have two persistence-units in your persistence.xml, each pointing to one datasource. Then, in your application, you load your EntityManager using the @PersistenceContext annotation, specifying a ["unitName"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html#unitName%28%29) parameter.

Comment: Thing is, the connection parameters are part of the app's input. I can't have them predefined in an XML. That's my requirement, which is easily doable with plain JDBC.

Comment: I see then two solutions: first, to interact via JMX with the container, to change the DataSource connection parameters on the fly, or have a "configurator" bean, but then, you'd have to manage Hibernate by yourself. The configurator can make use of Hibernate's configuration API: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic . Not sure about the "more than one DB simultaneously", though.

Comment: I checked the link you provided before and the explanation there assumes I'm using a hibernate.cfg.xml file, which I'm don't (as I said, I have a beans.xml file in the web-app). Maybe I can create my own cfg file that will import beans from the beans.xml. About the multiple connections, I think I simply need a session-factory per connection.